# How can I populate a web form from a spreadhseet or CSV file?

Tags: forms, webforms

I use a web form to create shipping labels, and I have a spreadsheet with the details of my customers. I found many tutorials showing how to populate a web form with static values, but I need to figure out how to automate the following:

1. Load web form
2. populate fields with values from spreadsheet Row 1
3. Submit web form
4. Reload web form
5. populate fields with values from spreadsheet Row 2
6. Submit web form
7. etc.

I use a Mac, and I tried this with Automator but I'm hitting a brick wall.

Cheers!

Comment: What steps have you tried/used in Automator?

Comment: So far I tried recording an automation, and building a service that copies spreadsheet fields to the clipboard, and then pastes the data into the web form that creates the shipping labels. My problem is that I'm flying blind because I can't find the right information to (at least) get started with the right actions and variables.

Answer (score 0):

Try looking at [Sheetrock](https://chriszarate.github.io/sheetrock/) and [Sheetsu](https://sheetsu.com)- two libraries for accessing Google Sheets spreadsheets from Javascript. I've never used them myself but I imagine that if you import your spreadsheet(s) into Google Sheets, either of those libraries will allow you to submit your forms with Javascript.

Comment: Thanks for your help Robert, but unfortunately Sheetrock is too advanced for my skillset. Sheetsu looks interesting though, I'll definitely dig into the documentation to see what it can do.